# generate random set of values from array

Tags: php

i want to get static length to get any random value from array.

PHP CODE:

in this below code how to get 5 random value from array?

```
$arr_history = array(23, 44,24,1,345,24,345,34,4,35,325,34,45,6457,57,12);
$lenght=5;
for ( $i = 1; $i < $lenght; $i++ )
     echo array_rand($arr_history);
```

Comment: Shuffle and slice or pass `5` as second argument to `array_rand`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php.

Comment: `shuffle($array); array_slice($array, 0, 5); //Implementation of Felix Kling's comment` ;)

Comment: @FelixKling Passing 5 as 2nd argument to `array_rand()` returns an array of keys, not values :)

Comment: @Jack: `array_rand` *always* returns a key or keys :) And why would that be a problem? The docs say: *"This is done so that you can pick random keys as well as values out of the array."*. *edit:* I see you created a proper answer. I think I slightly misunderstood your comment, but it's all good now :)

Comment: @FelixKling You can tell I use that function on a daily basis .. ahem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_rand()` to pick 5 random keys and then use those to intersect with the array keys; this keeps the original array intact.

```
$values = array_intersect_key($arr_history, array_flip(array_rand($arr_history, 5)));
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7dm1fM)

Alternatively, you can first shuffle the array in-place and then take the first or last 5 entries out:

```
shuffle($arr_history);
$values = array_slice($arr_history, -5);
```

This has the advantage that you can take multiple sets out consecutively without overlaps.

Comment: thats return static values in every refresh page

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$rand_value = array_rand($arr_history);

echo $rand_value;
```

REF: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

OR use :

```
shuffle($arr_history)
```

This will shuffle the order of the array : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php